# How to color code alternate rows using Python but color of row is to be same as previous row if certain column value is the same

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a tab delimited file which I add some formatting and write to out an Excel file. One request is to color code alternate rows, but there is a doc_no column in the file and for rows with the same doc_no the rows are to have the same color. Like in the example below:

[image: This is the output I want]

I have it where alternate rows are color coded and repeating doc_nos are higlighted (colors I used in the example are to illustrate, may not match the colors in the code).  I am not sure how to get the requested result and would appreciate any help.

[image: Current Output]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

infile = (r'C:\..\test.txt')

#read in tab delimited text file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\t', dtype = str, encoding='cp1252')

#delete columns with all null values
df.dropna(how='all', axis='columns', inplace=True)

#Get Date Range into variable date_range to print as HEADER and remove column from dataframe
date_range = df.iloc[0,0]
df.drop('Date Range', axis=1, inplace=True)

#replace NAN with empty string
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

dtstamp = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

#Writing dataframe to Excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\..\TEST-'+dtstamp+'.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1', startrow=2, index=False)

workbook = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

#--------------------------color code rows-------------------------------------
rcolor1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#D3D3D3'})
rcolor2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFE4E1'})                                     

for row in range(3,(len(df.index)+3), 2):
    ws.set_row(row,cell_format=rcolor2)

ws.conditional_format('B3:B'+str(len(df.index)+3),{'type': 'duplicate', 'format': rcolor1})
    
...

writer.save()
workbook.close()
```